# Type eror in call to Form Submit handler

Tags: forms, 8

I am writing a module that adds fields to Simplenews forms, including a custom submit handler. This is working fine on my test site, but when i migrate to my production site, I get the following error:

`Recoverable fatal error: Argument 2 passed to simple_conreg_simplenews_form_submit() must be an instance of FormStateInterface, instance of Drupal\\Core\\Form\\FormState given in /var/www/drupal/sites8/all/modules/simple_conreg/simple_conreg.module on line 193`

My handler is defined as:

```
function simple_conreg_simplenews_form_submit ($form, FormStateInterface $form_state)
```

I can get it to work on my production site by changing to:

```
function simple_conreg_simplenews_form_submit ($form, $form_state)
```

However, it would be nice to have type checking enforced.

Any idea why this is happening when the same definition works on the test site?

Comment: Have you actually aliased `FormStateInterface` in that context? What does the `use` statement look like? `Drupal\Core\Form\FormState` _is_ an instance of `Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface` so assuming you're referencing the right classes/interfaces in the right namespaces, you won't have a problem

Comment: Thanks, Clive. I should have thought to check the `use` statement! I had no `use` statement for `FormStateInterface`. My hook_form_alter had the full path to `FormStateInterface`, so perhaps on the test site that was enough for the submit function to find it. I've added a `use` statement, and everything seems to be good now.

Comment: @JamesShields you should work with an IDE. It will notify you of such mistakes.

Comment: Good point. Last time I tried to set one up, it didn't go well, so I've just been using a text editor. I should try again.